# Can I work in Georgia if I have a Schengen visa?

Tags: working-visas, schengen, georgia

I hold a Schengen visa, which is valid for 3 years. Can I work in Georgia on this Schengen visa without having any Georgian visa? If yes, for how long can I work in Georgia on a Schengen Visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer this question would be to work through the official ["Do I need a visa?"](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=956&lang=Eng) wizard.

The short answer seems to be "Yes", on the basis of [Ordinance 256](https://matsne.gov.ge/en/document/view/2867377), which gives a list of countries "*whose visa and/or residence permit holders may enter Georgia without a visa for an appropriate period and under appropriate conditions*" "*for 90 calendar days in any 180-day period.*"

To address the obvious point, I worked through the wizard on the basis of being a Moroccan citizen* with a French visa visiting for work purposes and it gave me a green light and a link to the text of the ordinance, so it seems that this ordinance does apply to working and not just to tourism.

However, it's still a good idea to work through the wizard yourself in case Georgia has some particular dispute with your country of citizenship and has made an exception in a different piece of legislation.

---

* I just picked the first country I thought of which wasn't in the list.